# Why does Python make self explicit?

Tags: python

Why does Python need an explicit `self` parameter in every argument list?

For example in the class Complex given in the documentation

```
class Complex: 

    def __init__(self, realpart, imagpart):
        self.r = realpart
        self.i = imagpart

    def conjugate(self):
        self.i = -self.i


x = Complex(3.0, -4.5) # 2 instead of 3?
x.conjugate()          # No parameters?
```

I initially found it profoundly confusing, that `__init__( )` seems to require 3
arguments, but you call `Complex( )` with only 2.

What is the reason the `self` parameter is explicit and not implicit?

Answer (score 9):

[Here](http://neopythonic.blogspot.ch/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html) is a good article from GvR on the matter. It talks about why the explicit `self` reference is here to stay.

Points he brings up among others:

reinforces the equivalency of

```
foo.meth(arg) == C.meth(foo, arg)
```

Being able to attach methods dynamically to a class, which can then be used from all both new and already existing objects of that class:

```
def meth(myself, arg):
   myself.val = arg
   return myself.val

# Poke the method into the class:
C.meth = meth
```

I encourage you to read the rest of the article. It is quite interesting.

Comment: `foo.meth(arg) == C.meth(foo, arg)` where you need this?

Comment: @DarekNędza As explained in the next paragraph, you can add additional methods to all objects of a class by simply adding a function with a self parameter to the class `C.newMethod = some_function_with_self`

Answer (score 2):

That's just how it is. Python's objects are actually just bags of properties (attributes). Some of these are regular values, but others are functions. They don't have any special binding to the class other than being an attribute of its instances. Method calling syntax is just a bit of sugar, taking care of passing the first parameter for you. In fact, methods are just plain functions, and you can call them as such, passing the first parameter explicitly.

I don't know exactly why this choice was made, but I assume it has to do with the fact that you can assign free functions as attributes to existing objects and then call them as methods; without the explicit `self` parameter, this would lead to even more confusion.

The mechanism is similar to Javascript, only that in Javascript, the implicitly-passed `this` argument is always introduced as a local variable named `this`, without the explicit parameter, whereas in Python, you can choose a name of your own liking through the explicit first parameter - `self` is not a keyword, merely a convention. This difference also means that you can use functions as methods more easily - a javascript function that uses `this` will break if used outside of an object context (or rather, in the context the default object, usually `window`), but in Python, you can pass a suitable object as the first parameter.

Note that other OOP flavors (Java, C++, etc.) also pass the `self` / `this` parameter into your method, but they do it implicitly, and `this` doesn't appear as an explicit argument. Those languages do not allow calling methods as free functions though (and vv., you can't use a free function as a method).

As to why it's called `__init__`: there is at least one advantage, namely that you can rename the class without having to rename the constructor. This makes refactoring easier and less error-prone. BTW, Python is not alone in this - PHP uses `__construct`, although class-named constructors are also supported, yet no longer recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "self" argument: It identifies an *instance* of a certain class. In C++, e.g., the exactly same thing is done - but under the hood.

Further reading: http://linuxgazette.net/issue56/orr.html

Answer (score 1):

(The following is a bit of an oversimplification, but should give you an idea how Python object creation proceeds.)

The statement

```
x = Complex(3.0, -4.5)
```

does not call `Complex.__init__` directly. Rather, it is somewhat identical to the following:

```
x = Complex.__new__(Complex, 3.0, -4.5)
Complex.__init__(x, 3.0, -4.5)
```

You may still think that is needlessly confusing. But it is designed this way for maximum flexibility. You can override `__new__` (which is usually just inherited from a base class)
to do something more (or different) than return an instance of the class. Most of the time you don't need to, though, so to keep you from needing to make two calls all the time just to create and initialize an object, it gets wrapped up in the shorthand of treating the type itself as a callable object to create and initialize an object in one step.

Comment: How is this related to `__new__`? The argument is, that you need to call methods with `n` formal methods with `n-1` arguments at the callsite. It's not specific to `__init__`.

Comment: I was just trying to show how/why `__init__` requires 3 arguments in the first place, when `Complex(3.0, -4.5)` seemingly only provides 2.