# Why must you pass self to python instance methods? Is there a reason to pass something else instead?

Tags: python, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python 'self' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019627/python-self-keyword)

In Python, instance methods must have the instance passed to them as an argument, like:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
         print self.name
```

What's the purpose of making this explicit? (Is it simply implicit < explicit?) In what circumstances would you would want to do pass something other than "self"?

Comment: I think you could call it whatever you want, it's just `self` by convention. However, when you make the method call, python implicitly passes the receiving object as the first argument.

Comment: Check out the second answer in the answer that @Lattyware linked to

Comment: Yes, that second answer is pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794918/confusion-on-python-class) where I linked to an [article by GvR explaining it in more detail](http://neopythonic.blogspot.ch/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html).

Answer (score 1):

A Python instance method is just a function that is bound to the instance. When called the instance always passes itself as the first argument.

The name `self` is just a convention. You can call it anything you want. So you could do this:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(s):
         print s.name
```

But don't, because it breaks convention. :)

Comment: Yes, I get that it can be anything. I'm just curious why it was implemented this way, instead of just being a property of instance methods that they have access to the instance (as in other implementations of class-based inheritance).

Comment: @futuraprime The answer is because a Python instance method is just a function that is bound to the instance. There is no way that could be true and not have the instance as a parameter.